# How to transfer/redirect calls without www to www.domain.com

Tags: asp.net

I have a website in asp.net.
I want all calls to: domain.com be redirected to www.domain.com

I found here the following:

> RewriteEngine on
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
>   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

However, this might cause a problem when using subdomain
xx.domain.com

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for any asp.net application at Global.asax file:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string FromHomeURL = http://yourdomain.com;    
   string ToHomeURL = http://www.yourdomain.com;

   if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains(FromHomeURL))
   {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location",
       Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace(FromHomeURL, ToHomeURL));
   }
}
```